# NumPy: matrix dot product incompatible with MATLAB

Tags: python, matlab, numpy

I'm trying to proceed some simple calculation in `NumPy`.

But it suddenly gives the results different with MATLAB calculations.

Here is the MATLAB example:

```
load temp; % here are the source matrices located

resp = ang_stv' * tmp;
respC = resp.'; % this is our variable to compare with Python

cd(fileparts(mfilename('fullpath')));
save('arythm_test.mat');
```

And here I try to calculate the same in Python:

```
dump_data = sp.io.loadmat("arythm_test.mat")

tmp = dump_data["tmp"]
ang_stv = dump_data["ang_stv"]
ref_resp = dump_data["respC"]

our_resp = np.dot(ang_stv.swapaxes(0, 1), tmp).swapaxes(0, 1)

np.testing.assert_allclose(our_resp, ref_resp)
```

Cannot you tell me, what am I doing wrong? And how to cope with it?

P.S. Here are [temp.mat](https://www.sendspace.com/file/7znhvj) and [arythm_test.mat](https://www.sendspace.com/file/1lzzmm)

Comment: What are the dimensions of `ang_stv` and `tmp`?

Comment: tmp.shape == (6L, 256L); ang_stv.shape == (6L, 300L)

Comment: Are the matrices complex?  The MATLAB operation `ang_stv'` is a conjugate complex transpose, while NumPy `swapaxes` is not.

Comment: Yes, they are complex.

Comment: Thank you, comrade! I missed that the ' operator is the conj transpose, and .' is simple transpose. Thank you!!!! ^__^

Comment: Also... `*` is not the dot product in MATLAB

Comment: Glad to help. I'm not that fluent in NumPy, so I won't write an answer to that - if you figured it out yourself, you can write a short answer to the question.

Comment: @Dan question of terminology. In NumPy, [`dot()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html) is a dot-product (scalar product) for vectors and a matrix multiplication for matrices, which is (more or less) the same as `*` in MATLAB. The `.*` in MATLAB is *not* a dot-product, even though it has a dot. The correct name would be Hadamard product.

Answer (score 1):

The answer was simple: the `.'` operator in MATLAB means simple transpose, and `'` operator means transpose with complex conjugation. Oy vey...

```
tmp = dump_data["tmp"]
ang_stv = dump_data["ang_stv"]

print "tmp.shape", tmp.shape
print "ang_stv.shape", ang_stv.shape

ref_resp = dump_data["respC"]

our_resp = np.dot(np.conj(ang_stv.swapaxes(0, 1)), tmp).swapaxes(0, 1)
```

Comment: Could you add, how you fixed that in NumPy? That way future readers can profit more from the question.

Comment: It matlab expressions like `x.+y`, the dot means apply element by element.

Comment: Yes, but `.'` is a single special operator.